# Run specific method before and after every call to implementation of an interface

Tags: c#

My goal is to have methods `init()` and `complete(result)` which will run before and after every method of a chosen class.
Similar to how the `ActionFilterAttribute` in ASP.NET has `OnActionExecuting` and `OnActionExecuted` methods that run before and after whatever method you apply them to.

There are multiple interfaces I would like to apply the same `init()` and `complete(result)` methods to, and I want to avoid code duplication and keep code easy to understand if possible.

From what I can tell, there doesn't seem to be an elegant solution. So far, I have 3 options:

**Option 1:**

```
    public interface MyImportantMethods
    {
        object f();
        object g();
    }

    public class MyClass : MyImportantMethods
    {
        public object f()
        {
            // Do things
        }

        public object g()
        {
            // Do things
        }
    }

    public class WrappedMyClass : MyImportantMethods
    {
        private MyImportantMethods ActualContent;

        public MyModifiedClass(MyImportantMethods actualContent)
        {
            this.ActualContent = actualContent;
        }

        public object f()
        {
            init();
            object result = this.ActualContent.f();
            complete(result);
            return result;
        }

        public object g()
        {
            init();
            object result = this.ActualContent.g();
            complete(result);
            return result;
        }
    }
```

- Pros: The class with the implementation is completely separate from
  the one which calls `init()` and `complete()`, so it is more readable and
  simpler to understand.
- Cons: It is easy for someone not familiar with the code to use the
  wrong one. Requires a different class for each interface I want to
  apply it to.

**Option 2:**

```
    public interface MyImportantMethods
    {
        object f();
        object g();
    }


    class Wrapper: IDisposable
    {   
        public object result;
        public Wrapper()
        {
            init();
        }

        void Dispose()
        {
            complete(result);
        }
    }

    public class MyModifiedClass {
        private void f()
        {
            using (var wrapper = new Wrapper(() => completeF()))
            {
                // Do Things
                wrapper.result = result;
            }
        }

        private void g()
        {
            using (var wrapper = new Wrapper(() => completeG()))
            {
                // Do Things
                wrapper.result = result;
            }
        }
    }
```

- Pros: Not possible to use the wrong class. May be possible to use one
  IDisposable class for all interfaces, if I use a reflection trick
- Cons: Code will look much more cluttered and hard to understand for a
  new reader, especially if the declaration of wrapper takes multiple
  lines or wrapper needs more than one parameter from the result (both
  are true in my case). Also relies on the caller to set the result.

**Option 3:**

```
    public abstract class MyImportantMethodsBase
    {
        public object f()
        {
            init();
            object result = this.fImplementation();
            complete(fResult);
            return result;
        }

        public object g()
        {
            init();
            object result = this.gImplementation();
            complete(result);
            return result;
        }

        private abstract object fImplementation();

        private abstract object gImplementation();
    }

    public class MyModifiedClass : MyImportantMethodsBase {
        private object void fImplementation()
        {
            // Do Things
        }

        private object gImplementation()
        {
            // Do Things
        }
    }
```

- Pros: Not possible to use the wrong class. The class with the
  implementation is completely separate from the one which calls init()
  and complete(), so it is more readable and simpler to understand.

  Cons: Less simple for a reader to understand.

Is there really no way as simple and understandable as the `ActionFilterAttribute` to accomplish my goal?

Comment: IMHO, option number 3 is the best, and I don't believe it's hard to understand. As You mention ActionFilterAttribute, why not create an attribute and use it in Your classes?

Comment: I like Option3, too:  is an example of Template Method design pattern which many programmers recognize

Comment: @Skaparate you need something that would use attributes - you can't expect that just adding couple attributes will magically implement method/interface interception available in most dependency injection controllers. If you are interested in what OP is likely trying to do you can check out how it is done with Unity (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178466(v=pandp.30).aspx) or in general https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23%20dependency%20injection%20interception

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov, of course You need to implement them, they are not "magical" :P. The thing is that is not too hard to implement and may be the user doesn't want (or doesn't know about it) to use DI.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps Option 1 with Factory Pattern is enough: Make constructor private so it can't be used the wrong way. Make a static function in the same class to construct the subject object and then create a wrapper object around it, returning that of a type that is the common shared interface.

However, If you have many classes to wrap, runtime code generation (or design time .tt code generation) could help you out. calling WrapperGenerator.Create(newObject) where T is the Interface and newObject is the private constructed object which implements that interface. The Create function reflects on the Interface, then you create a new class on the fly based on that interface which will wrap with the extra function calls around the functions found one the base object. Any newly created wrapper classes would be cached for the same Interface.

```
class WrapperGenerator
{
    static Dictionary<Type,ConstructorInfo> cachedWrappers = new ...();
    public static T Create<T>(object wrappedObject)
    {
        ConstructorInfo wrapperConstructor = null;
        var found = cachedWrappers.TryGet(typeof(T), out wrapperConstructor);
        if (found)
        {
            return (T)wrapperConstructor.Invoke(wrappedObject);
        }

        //cachedWrapper not found
        wrapperConstructor = GenerateNewConstructor(typeof(T));
        cachedWrappers.Add(typeof(T), wrapperConstructor);

        return (T)wrapperConstructor.Invoke(wrappedObject);
    }

    static long Counter = 0;
    static ConstructorInfo GenerateNewConstructor(Type t)
    {
        var methodList = t.GetMethods(...);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("namespace WrapperClasses {\r\n");
        var ClassName = "Wrapper" + Counter++;
        var InterfaceName = t.FullName;
        sb.AppendFormat("public class {0} {{\r\n", ClassName);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0} wrappedObject = null;\r\n", ClassName);
        sb.AppendFormat("public Wrapper{0}({1} wrappedObject) {"\r\n, ClassName, InterfaceName);
        sb.Append("   this.wrappedObject = wrappedObject;\r\n");
        sb.Append("}\r\n");
        foreach (var m in methodList)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("public {0} {1}({2}) {{", m.ReturnType.., m.Name, ParameterDeclarationsSegment(m));
            sb.AppendFormat("    init();\r\n"); 
            sb.AppendFormat("    var result = wrappedObject.{0}({1});\r\n", m.Name, ParameterPassthroughSegment(m));    
            sb.AppendFormat("    complete(result);\r\n");   
            sb.Append("};\r\n");    
        }
        //ETC.. closing class and namespace
        var LoadedAssembly = Compiler.Compile(sb,...);
        var getWrapperType = LoadedAssembly.SearchType(ClassName);
        return getWrapperType.GetConstructors()[0];
    }
}
```

Note: You should implement locking around the cachedWrappers.